# Ansible loop over sub item

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I struggle to loop over a subvar in jinja file

By now I've got this in my jinja file :

```
{% for item in rsyslog_custom_templates.name %}
$template "{{ item.1.template_tag }}","{{ item.1.template_dir }}"
if $syslogtag == "{{ item.1.template_tag }}" then -?"{{ item.1.template_tag }}"
{% endfor %}
```

not working well with item.1

and in my group_vars:

```
rsyslog_custom_templates:
 name: 
   projet1:
     - template_tag: "log1"
       template_dir: "/dir1"
     - template_tag: "log2"
       template_dir: "/dir2"
   projet2:
     - template_tag: "log1"
       template_dir: "/dir1"
```

I want to loop over var in each project name and create unique file from it, if you have any advise on this !

i expect to have:

projet1.conf file:

```
$template log1,/dir1
if $syslogtag == log1 then -?log1
$template log2,/dir2
if $syslogtag == log2 then -?log2
```

projet2.conf file:

```
$template log1,/dir1
if $syslogtag == log1 then -?log1
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/{{ item.key }}.conf"
        content: |
          {% for j in item.value %}
          $template {{ j.template_tag }},{{ j.template_dir }}
          if $syslogtag == {{ j.template_tag }} then -?{{ j.template_tag }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ rct.name|dict2items }}"
```

gives what you want

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/projet1.conf 
$template log1,/dir1
if $syslogtag == log1 then -?log1
$template log2,/dir2
if $syslogtag == log2 then -?log2
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/projet2.conf 
$template log1,/dir1
if $syslogtag == log1 then -?log1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    rct:
      name: 
        projet1:
          - template_tag: "log1"
            template_dir: "/dir1"
          - template_tag: "log2"
            template_dir: "/dir2"
        projet2:
          - template_tag: "log1"
            template_dir: "/dir1"

  tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/{{ item.key }}.conf"
        content: |
          {% for j in item.value %}
          $template {{ j.template_tag }},{{ j.template_dir }}
          if $syslogtag == {{ j.template_tag }} then -?{{ j.template_tag }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ rct.name|dict2items }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! used the content in my jinja file and it works really well